# Error on Lightning input while changing it's type dynamically

Tags: lightning-web-components

Initially lightning input component loaded with **type="date"**, on button click we change it's type to **type="number"**. But we receiving following error `TypeError: Cannot convert undefined or null to object`.

I have tried below code.

html file

```
<lightning-input type={testType} value={testValue} variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
<lightning-button label="change to number type" onclick={clickToChange}></lightning-button>
```

js file

```
export default class testComponent extends LightningElement {

    testType = 'date';
    testValue = '2020-09-07';
    
    clickToChange() {
        this.testType = 'number';
        this.testValue = null;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is something to do with the testValue property you are setting up in click event method. if you remove the line this.testValue = null, framework will not give you any error.

Comment: @AnkurGupta, Thanks, But I need to set empty value for number input? Is there any other solution or workaround?.

Comment: it will automatically becomes empty once lightning input type changes. isn't it?

Comment: Lightning input value changed to null what about testValue?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of making the `testValue=null` in `clickToChange` just change the type

```
clickToChange() {
        this.testType = 'number';
        console.log(this.testType);
        // this.testValue = 'null';
    }
```

and in your HTML file add the `onChange` in your `lightning-input` and update `testValue`  in `handleChange` function in js.

Below is the code example:

```
<lightning-input onchange={handleChange} type={testType} value={testValue} variant="label-hidden"></lightning-input>
<lightning-button label="change to number type" onclick={clickToChange}></lightning-button>

handleChange(event) {
        this.testValue = event.target.value;
        console.log(this.testValue);
    }
```

Comment: Thanks you your reply. In this case the onChange event not fired after changing the input type.

Comment: It will only fired when you start typing  on lightning-input

Comment: Before typing the lightning input, click the save button the testValue is not changed.